C++20 ranges - How to store a composed ranges view in class member
How can I store a C++20 ranges composed view as a class member?
I tried with the following code which works with in general, but if I put the struct into a header, GCC warns me that splitter::view has internal linkage. (-Werror=subobject-linkage)
I think GCC is right in this case, but I don't know how to set it to external linkage.
But I think I have a more fundamental problem here, which is I cannot name the type of the range view. In theory I could type that out, but it's a pain if I add another filter to the view.
#include <ranges>
#include <string_view>

#include <fmt/core.h>

struct splitter {
    static constexpr auto split = [](std::string_view command) {
          return command
              | std::views::split(' ')
              | std::views::filter([](auto range) { return !std::ranges::empty(range); })
              | std::views::transform([](auto range) { return std::string_view(range); });
    };

    using ViewType = decltype(split(std::declval<std::string_view>()));

    ViewType view;

    splitter(std::string_view str)
        : view(split(str))
    {
    }
};

int main() {

    std::string_view str = " test foo  bar ";

    splitter sptl(str);
    for (auto s : sptl) {
        fmt::print("token {} with size {}", s, s.size());
    }
}

Here's a godbolt link to the header version: https://godbolt.org/z/avMhqofcf

Why not write e regular function instead of lambda?

You can just make splitter an alias for the adaptors' compositions like this.

The type of a lambda in a header file will be different in every translation unit.  So it will have internal linkage.

No lambda no problem: https://godbolt.org/z/fcMGP3a47

@康桓瑋 I like that you can do that. But originally I wanted to store an iterator in the splitter class as an internal state. With the stored adaptor composition I have the same issue. But I have to rethink my approach.

@Jarod42, thanks, a function outside the class works. If you post this as an answer I can accept that.

@MarekR, thanks for the example, I had another error when I tried this, but your example helped. If you post it I can accept.

Issue is that inside the class, class is still incomplete
So you have limited access to its internal.
changing lambda to regular function, and moving it from the class solve the issue:
inline constexpr auto split(std::string_view command)
{
      return command
          | std::views::split(' ')
          | std::views::filter([](auto range) { return !std::ranges::empty(range); })
          | std::views::transform([](auto range) { return std::string_view(range); });
}

struct splitter {
    using ViewType = decltype(split(std::declval<std::string_view>()));

    ViewType view;

    splitter(std::string_view str)
        : view(split(str))
    {
    }
};

Demo
